# WTForms - Built in message translation

Tags: python, wtforms

I'm using Python 3.7.4 with Flask 1.1.1 and WTforms 2.2.1 in web app.

I'm trying to create `DateField` like this:

`user_birth = DateField('Datum narození', format='%d-%m-%y')`

If user wrongly fill date and submit it, there is message: "Not a valid date value" which I would like to display in a language other than English (Czech for example).

In `StringField` I'm doing it this way:

`username = StringField('Přezdívka', [validators.Length(min=1, max=30, message='Pole musí obsahovat hodnotu od 1 do 30 znaků.')])`

But for `DateField` I'm not able to put any validator.

Question: Is possible to insert any validator to `DateField` and how?

Answer (score 2):

Here's the definition of `DateField` from [the source](https://github.com/wtforms/wtforms/blob/1ef632903e8fec80edadf1a65273fd9a417bf838/src/wtforms/fields/core.py#L849-L864):

```py
class DateField(DateTimeField):
    """
    Same as DateTimeField, except stores a `datetime.date`.
    """

    def __init__(self, label=None, validators=None, format="%Y-%m-%d", **kwargs):
        super(DateField, self).__init__(label, validators, format, **kwargs)

    def process_formdata(self, valuelist):
        if valuelist:
            date_str = " ".join(valuelist)
            try:
                self.data = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_str, self.format).date()
            except ValueError:
                self.data = None
                raise ValueError(self.gettext("Not a valid date value"))
```

There you can see a `ValueError` is raised from within the `process_formdata()` method that doesn't allow you to supply a specific error message. However, notice that the error message is wrapped in a call to `self.gettext()` - this is to allow for message translations, and there is a CZ translation available.

The translation object is passed to the form fields from the `Form` object, so you can either set the translation on a per-instance basis, or for all forms using class inheritance.

**Translating on a per-form basis**:

```py
from wtforms import DateField, Form
from werkzeug.datastructures import MultiDict


class MyForm(Form):
    user_birth = DateField('Datum narození', format='%d-%m-%y')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # this fakes an invalid form from webserver
    request_form = MultiDict([("user_birth", "invalid date")])
    form = MyForm(request_form, meta={'locales': ['cs_CZ']})
    print(form.user_birth.process_errors)  # ['Neplatná hodnota pro datum.']
```

**Translating with common base class:**

```py
class BaseForm(Form):
    class Meta:
        locales = ['cs_CZ']


class MyForm(BaseForm):
    user_birth = DateField('Datum narození', format='%d-%m-%y')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    request_form = MultiDict([("user_birth", "invalid date")])
    form = MyForm(request_form)
    print(form.user_birth.process_errors)  # ['Neplatná hodnota pro datum.']
```

All of the supported locales can be found [here](https://github.com/wtforms/wtforms/tree/master/src/wtforms/locale), and the supporting documentation [here](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/stable/i18n.html#internationalization-i18n).